# Retrieve domain name from WCF request

Tags: c#, wcf

I use following code to retrieve domain name from WCF operation context.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Security.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity;
domain = identity.Name.Split('\\')[0];
```

While its working as expected in my machine when I deploy the resulting domain name always comes as NT AUTHORITY.

Deployment server runs Windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7. I am using basicHttpBinding and following is the binding configuration. Can any one point out anything that I am doing incorrectly?

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIdentityService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```